# MailKit - smtp.Connect throw exception in C# .Net

Tags: mailkit

Exception while connecting to the server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or an established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.

1.) able to ping the server

2.) telnet smtp.office365.com 587 respond as expected.

```
public ConnectSmtpServer()
{
    using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
    string _SmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com";
    int _portNumber = 587;

    Console.WriteLine("Welcome!");
    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            smtp.Timeout = 30 * 1000;
            smtp.Connect(_SmtpServer, _portNumber, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

            Console.WriteLine("Test smtp connection using MailKit.Net !");
            smtp.Connect(_SmtpServer, _portNumber, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: telnet smtp.office365.com 587 respond as expected, so the port is not blocked.

Comment: Use **SecureSocketOptions.StartTls** Office 365 implements the STARTTLS command on port 587.

Comment: Thanks, John for taking the timeout and reviewing the question, however, we did try passing up the 'SecureSocketOptions.StartTls'  as well, that's result in the same error. This is kind of clueless as we are already able to telnet the server with port.